# Ubuntu (18.04.4 LTS) cursor randomly turns into a '+'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, ubuntu-18.04, display-driver

This issue is since last 2 days and its quite frequent (ones every minute or so), One had to double click to bring it back to normal cursor. Also if we try to select an area it draws weird shapes.

As few of the answers to similar issues suggests I tried to run killall -KILL import, still no change.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCCM.jpg)

Comment: Are you doing this on a laptop or a desktop?  I have had this on a laptop where the pad of my left hand is on the touchpad when I am moving my right finger around the rest of the touchpad.  Never had it on a desktop

Comment: @cup I'm facing this issue on a Laptop, but I'm using an external mouse. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you disabled the touchpad?  In my case, it was the gestures - I was touching two points of the touchpad at the same time: on with the pad of my left hand and the other with my right finger.  Gets especially annoying on a 10" notebook with a tiny touchpad.  Once I disabled the touchpad, everything was fine - otherwise my text would go from 100 to 200%

Comment: You need to keep you left hand off the keyboard.   You may not think you are touching the touchpad but it is very sensitive.

Comment: Ah, I'm not touching my laptop, using it at a distance with external keyboard and mouse. But i did try disabling my touchpad.

Comment: It is a different problem them.